# What JavaScript object copy function works with greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, object, copy, greasemonkey

I know there is another question related to copying objects in JavaScript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript), but the code they provide does not work with greasemonkey. From what I was able to trace, the code for the accepted answer dies/ stops at the line :

```
var temp = new obj.constructor();
```

Is there any way to see what went wrong ?

It's not really necessary I use the same function for the object copying, but I would like something that works. Do you know some function?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
var a = {
    yo: 'hello',
    do: function() {alert(this.yo + ' world');}
};

var cloneStructor = function() {};
cloneStructor.prototype = a;

var b = new cloneStructor();
a.yo = 'goodbye';
b.yo = 'what\'s up';

a.do();
b.do();
```

Comment: won't this just be a reference and not a true copy?

Comment: The example I provided uses the 'new' keyword and seems to work--a and b end up with different properties. Another approach I found uses JSON.eval(JSON.stringify(cloneMe)). That might be worth trying. Otherwise, you could loop through all the properties manually and reconstruct things.